# Connecting QQuickImageProvider

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have to connect a QQuickImageProvider with a class to pass an image that the image provider must return, but I am not finding a way to do that.

I have a class called provedorImagem.cpp with a virtual requestImage function implemented and I have also a class called processaImagem.cpp that is the class to perform modification at the image.

The provedorImagem class is passed to engine as a provider: engine.addImageProvider("provedor", provedorImg) in main.cpp

What I need is a way to connect a slot in the provider in main.cpp with a signal in processaImagem.cpp. Doing that the processaImagem.cpp can send the image I must return to Qml to provedorImagem.cpp and send it back to Qml.

Could someone help me?

Code below

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <QtQml>

#include "processaimagem.h"
#include "provedorimagem.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<processaImagem>("ProcessaImagemQml", 1, 0, "ProcessaImagem");

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    provedorImagem *provedorImg = new provedorImagem;

    //------------  I have to create a connection here between the provider slot and a signal in processaImagem with the image to provide  -----------------

    engine.addImageProvider("provedor", provedorImg);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

processaImagem.h

```
#ifndef PROCESSAIMAGEM_H
#define PROCESSAIMAGEM_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QImage>
#include <QQmlEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include <QQuickImageProvider>

#include "provedorimagem.h"

class processaImagem : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public slots:
    QString recebeImagem(const QString &caminho);

public:
    processaImagem(QObject *parent = 0);

    QImage carregaImagem(const QString &caminho);

signals:
    void enviaImagem(QImage);
};

#endif // PROCESSAIMAGEM_H
```

processaImagem.cpp

```
#include "processaimagem.h"

#include <QDebug>

processaImagem::processaImagem(QObject *parent)
{

}

QString processaImagem::recebeImagem(const QString &caminho)
{
    QImage imagem = this->carregaImagem(caminho);

    QString caminhoRetorno;

    if(imagem.isNull())
    {
        qDebug() << "Erro ao receber a imagem";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Imagem recebida";
        caminhoRetorno = "image://provedor/imagemEditada";
    }

    return caminhoRetorno;
}

QImage processaImagem::carregaImagem(const QString &caminho)
{
    QUrl caminhoImagem(caminho);
    QQmlEngine *engine = QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this)->engine();
    QQmlImageProviderBase *imageProviderBase = engine->imageProvider(caminhoImagem.host());
    QQuickImageProvider *imageProvider = static_cast<QQuickImageProvider*>(imageProviderBase);

    QSize imageSize;
    QString imageId = caminhoImagem.path().remove(0, 1);
    QImage imagem = imageProvider->requestImage(imageId, &imageSize, imageSize);

    if(imagem.isNull())
    {
        qDebug() << "Erro ao carregar a imagem";
        imagem = QImage();
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Imagem carregada";
    }

    return imagem;
}
```

provedorimagem.h

```
#ifndef PROVEDORIMAGEM_H
#define PROVEDORIMAGEM_H

#include <QImage>
#include <QQuickImageProvider>

class provedorImagem : public QQuickImageProvider
{
public:
    provedorImagem();

    QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize);

    void carregaImagem();

public slots:
    void carregaImagem(QImage imagemRecebida);

private:
    QImage imagem;
};

#endif // PROVEDORIMAGEM_H
```

provedorimagem.cpp

```
#include "provedorimagem.h"

#include <QDebug>

provedorImagem::provedorImagem() : QQuickImageProvider(QQuickImageProvider::Image)
{

}

QImage provedorImagem::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
{
    if(imagem.isNull())
    {
        qDebug() << "Erro ao prover a imagem";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "Imagem provida";
    }

    return imagem;
}

void provedorImagem::carregaImagem(QImage imagemRecebida)
{
    imagem = imagemRecebida;
}
```

Comment: If you make clear to the reader what question you are asking that will improve your chances of getting a useful reply.  In this case it would help if you explained which line of code is causing problems and what kind of problem - compile time error?  Run time error?  Something else?  Reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) might give you some ideas.

Comment: Ok Frank! I edited the post to try to make it better to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question
Problem solved. Here is the solution step by step:

1 - Create a `class` that inherits from `QQuickImageProvider` and `QObject` and inside it create a `Image` member `(QImage)` that is the image to be provided.

```
class provedorImagem : public QObject, public QQuickImageProvider
```

Implement the `virtual requestImage` method. This is the method that will return the image to Qml

```
QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
```

Create a method to load the provider’s image to return

```
void provedorImagem::carregaImagem(QImage imagemRecebida)
{
    imagem = imagemRecebida;
}
```

Now set it as the engine image provider in the `main.cpp` file

```
provedorImagem *provedorImg = new provedorImagem;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ProvedorImagem", provedorImg);
```

2 - Create another `class` that inherits from `QObject`.

```
class processaImagem : public QObject
```

Inside this class you must implement a method that will get the image from `camera` provider, perform the image modifications and return the modified image.
PS: The `p_caminhoImagem` is a `property` that I created inside the `processaImagem class` that receives the `camera preview path`.

```
QImage processaImagem::carregaImagem()
{
    QUrl caminhoImagem(p_caminhoImagem);
    QQmlEngine *engine = QQmlEngine::contextForObject(this)->engine();
    QQmlImageProviderBase *imageProviderBase = engine->imageProvider(caminhoImagem.host());
    QQuickImageProvider *imageProvider = static_cast<QQuickImageProvider*>(imageProviderBase);


    QSize imageSize;
    QString imageId = caminhoImagem.path().remove(0, 1);
    QImage imagem = imageProvider->requestImage(imageId, &imageSize, imageSize);

    if(imagem.isNull())
    {
        imagem = QImage();
    }
    else
    {
        //Perform the modifications
    }

    return imagem;
}
```

3 - Now is the main part. The image `requestImage` provider method  must receive the modified image from the `processaImagem class` to provide it to QML. To do it the provider `class pointer` must be accessible to the QML file, so, in the `main.cpp` file just make the pointer available to QML as a `property`

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ProvedorImagem", provedorImg);
```

and register the `processaImagem class` as a QML type

```
qmlRegisterType<processaImagem>("ProcessaImagemQml", 1, 0, "ProcessaImagem");
```

Now we link it inside the QML file

```
ProvedorImagem.carregaImagem(processaImagem.carregaImagem());
```

4 - It is done. Now just request the image from the provider:

```
imagemPreview.source = "image://provedor/imagemEditada_" + camera.numeroImagem.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

For image provider to work one of the below methods needs to be implemented:

```
virtual QImage requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize& requestedSize);
virtual QPixmap requestPixmap(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize& requestedSize);
virtual QQuickTextureFactory *requestTexture(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize);
```

Derived from the example above.

```
QImage provedorImagem::requestImage(const QString &id, QSize *size, const QSize &requestedSize)
{
    // the id has value like "imagemEditada" or the last word in URL
    if(imagem.isNull())
    {
        qDebug() << "Erro ao prover a imagem";
    }
    else if (caminhoRetorno.endsWith(id, Qt::CaseInsensitive)) // that will be a check for id after "provedor"
    {
        qDebug() << "Imagem provida";
        return imagem; // provide an image
    }
    return QImage(); // no match with id from url
}
```

And your QML code should have something like:

```
    Image {
        // // //
        source: "image://provedor/imagemEditada"
    }
```

There is a nice complete [example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-imageprovider-example.html) in Qt docs.

@GuiDupas, from your corrected question it seems that you would like to recognize the image provided. The method to check the last word in URL with QString::endsWith is for the demo of course.

Comment: Hello Alexander. The method is implemented in provedorImagem.cpp. Now I need a way to connect a slot inside the provider with a signal in processaImagem.cpp. This slot must receive a QImage to be returned by the provider.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are trying to send a image from qt(c++) code to display in qml.
Please look the below camera application source.  Passing the camera image to qml using QQuickPaintedItem.

https://github.com/econsysqtcam/qtcam.git

Have a look at  videostreaming.cpp/ videostreaming.h and their connection to qml.  Hope that helps